# Creating new matrix based on dictionary values and a list

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

The following is a simplified example:

```
val = [10,23,45,31,78,43,1,67,82]

indx = [1,4,5,8]
indx2 = [3,6,7]
indx3 = [0,2]

samp = {}
samp[0] = indx
samp[1] = indx2
samp[2] = indx3
```

Say I have a dictionary (samp) that has two groups: Group 0 and Group 1.
The dictionary has indicies for values in the vector val.

I want to pull out all of the values in val based on the given group in the dictionary by creating a 8 X 2 matrix,
Where i have the group and the value in two columns in order by index so it looks like this:

```
val  group
10   2
23   0
45   2
31   0
87   0
43   1
1    1
67   0
82   1
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get this

```
[(j, next(k for k,v in samp.items() if i in v)) for i,j in enumerate(val)]
```

Output:

```
[(10, 2),
 (23, 0),
 (45, 2),
 (31, 1),
 (78, 0),
 (43, 0),
 (1, 1),
 (67, 1),
 (82, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dictionary comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to reverse the key, value pairs in dictionary and then use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(val,columns=['val'])
d = {value1:key  for key,value in samp.items() for value1 in value}
df['group'] = df.index.map(d)

print(df)
   val  group
0   10      2
1   23      0
2   45      2
3   31      1
4   78      0
5   43      0
6    1      1
7   67      1
```

---

```
print(d)
{1: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 8: 0, 3: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 0: 2, 2: 2}
```

What if the values are numpy arrays:

```
indx = np.array([1,4,5,8])
indx2 = np.array([3,6,7])
indx3 = np.array([0,2])

samp = {}
samp[0] = indx
samp[1] = indx2
samp[2] = indx3

print(samp)
{0: array([1, 4, 5, 8]), 1: array([3, 6, 7]), 2: array([0, 2])}

d = {value1:key  for key,value in samp.items() for value1 in value}

print(d)
{1: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 8: 0, 3: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 0: 2, 2: 2}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep.  What if the values in the dictonaries are numpy arrays?   I noticed that .items() is not supported for np.arrays

Comment: @Sheila It would work even if the values are numpy arrays check the update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using pandas that outputs a (8,2) numpy matrix:

```
val = [10,23,45,31,78,43,1,67,82]

indx = [1,4,5,8]
indx2 = [3,6,7]
indx3 = [0,2]

indices = [indx, indx2, indx3]

def get_group(x):
    for i,indx_arr in enumerate(indices):
        if x in indx_arr:
            return i

pairs = [(v,get_group(i)) for i,v in enumerate(val)]
np.asarray(pairs)

array([[10,  2],
   [23,  0],
   [45,  2],
   [31,  1],
   [78,  0],
   [43,  0],
   [ 1,  1],
   [67,  1],
   [82,  0]])
```